# How to open existing app in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

when I run an already developed(working in iPhone 4S) app in iPhone 5 without the launch image for 4-inch screen, the UI is breaking. i.e, it is not showing the letter-box view(view with a black patch on both top and bottom of the screen) instead it simply shows some white patch in the bottom alone and shifts the entire UI towards top. I know about the launch image related issues, but without that it should at least show the letter-box type view. But that even is not working. May know what could be the reason?

Comment: Have you ever had a 4-inch launch image, maybe briefly as a test? If so, it may still be around, even if you thought you deleted it. Try removing the app from your phone, cleaning the build folder (in Xcode, Product->Clean), then try running your app again.